# Trying to create user with membership using Devise - Need help with controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, routes, nested-forms

I have a standard devise installation, and I'm trying to add in functionality to add a user with a gym membership from an admin panel.

routes.rb

```
  devise_for :users

  resources :users
```

I am creating the user from the gym controller, so this is my gym action

```
  def members
    @gym = Gym.find(params[:id])
    @user = User.new
    @user.gym_users.build
    @roles = Role.all
  end
```

The gym_user is accepted in the user model

```
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :gym_users
```

Then here is a portion of my form

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>

<%= f.label :email %><br />
<%= f.text_field :email %>

<% f.fields_for :gym_users do |builder| %>

    <%= builder.label :item_id, "Membership Level" %><br />
    <%= builder.collection_select(:item_id, @gym.membership_items, :id, :name, {:include_blank => true}) %>

<% end %>
```

<% end %>

What I'm having trouble with is my user controller where I actually create the user.  This is the route for the membership page where the user is created

```
 match 'gyms/:id/members' => 'gyms#members'
```

Finally, here's the create method on my users_controller

```
  def create
@user = User.new(params[:user])

if @user.save
  :notice => "User created successfully"
  render :new
else
  render :new
end
```

end

What I'm not sure is how to send back to that url when there is an error so that my model errors go with it, or redirect when it completes correctly.

Comment: Why you dont create user inside of gym#members action? If some errors will occur there, the approproate view will be rendered with all fields filled by user and validation errors etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by making it an ajax call which eliminated the need for a redirect.